# Colocar un section debajo del header

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema.. tengo un header y debajo quiero colocar un section, pero al crear el section, se coloca arriba de la pagina por delante del header.
Tengo un nav creado que quiero que este por delante, asique e utilizado el z-index (supongo que el problema del section tiene que ver con el z-index, ¿cierto?).

Gracias.

```
nav{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #44acde;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 700px;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto 0;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

 nav li {
     list-style: none;
 }


nav a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}


nav a img{
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

/*-----------------------HEADER-----------------------*/

header{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #071d56;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

header img{
        margin-top: 200px;
}


#video_background {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: .5;
}



/*-----------------------MAIN-----------------------*/


#main{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;

    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Puedes enseñarnos tu html? Cómo se ve ahora?

Comment: Coloca el código completo incluyendo el html para poder ayudarte.